# Prove that $B^tAB = [B^tAB]^t$ when $A_{nxn}$ is symmetric and $B_{nxm}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $B^tAB = [B^tAB]^t$ when $A_{nxn}$ is symmetric and $B_{nxm}$ is a general matrix.
I started solving this way:
Let's look at a general element in $B^tAB$ - $(B^tAB)_{i, j} = b_{j, i} * a_{i, j} * b_{i, j}$
At this point the teacher stopped checking and redacted 14 points - "incorrect equality". Why?

Comment: I don't know why, but why don't you just find $(B^t AB)^t$?

Comment: Values are not given

Comment: Yes, but you can use the general formula: $(MN)^t = N^t M^t$

Comment: I know it now...

Comment: Check the Wikipedia article for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that if $A=(a_{ij}) ,B=(b_{ij})$ then $C=AB ;C=(c_{ij})$

where $c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you wrote is multiplying matrix elements "point-wise", which is not how we usually multiply matrices.

Solving the given problem is much simpler. Since $A$ is symmetric, $A = A^t$. Also, it's a theorem that $(AB)^t = B^t A^t$, that is, when taking the transpose of a product, you multiply the transposes of the terms in the product *in reverse order*. Finally, $(A^t)^t = A$, i.e., transposing twice returns the original matrix.

So $(B^t A B)^t = B^t A^t (B^t)^t = B^t A B$.